# php how join string date and time separates and convert format Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, mysql

I have two string separates date and time, I need you to join these and convert in format Y-m-d H:i:s

time
214323

date
131016

```
<?php

$data0 ="214323,131016" ;

$data1 = explode( ',', $data0);

$time = $data1[0];
$date = $data1[1];
```

I need you 2016-10-13 21:43:23

I used this solution but when I use my vars I get a error PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /root/date2.php on line 10

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');

$data0 ="214323,131016" ;
$data1 = explode( ',', $data0);

$date = $data1[0];
$time = $data1[1];
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('His,dmy', '$date,$time');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Just replace the , by null and operate the `date()` function...

Comment: coulld you give me a example

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/DateTime) class to parse the special format and format it into the desired format.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('His,dmy', '214323,131016');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

https://3v4l.org/UV48B

Comment: how include this class ?

Comment: DateTime is included in PHP core.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Then it's immediately time to upgrade to a more recent PHP version. PHP 5.1 is 10 years old (a decade!). https://secure.php.net/eol.php

Comment: Thank you so much Charlotte you are a rock apreciate

Comment: $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('His,dmy', '214323,131016');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: $data0 ="214323,131016" ;
$data1 = explode( ',', $data0);
$date = $data1[0];
$time = $data1[1];
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('His,dmy', '$time,$date');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /root/date2.php on line 10

Comment: Using my vars doesn't work PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /root/date2.php on line 10

Comment: You pass `$data0` to `createFromFormat`, using `explode` doesn't help you

Comment: Is there a way how conver only string time to H:i:s ?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Why did you remove the accept flag? It does answer your question. That you don't understand that you really only need to pass the complete string and not break it up with `explode` and then try to make the **same string** again, where you fail horribly - is not my fault.